# Make Sublime Text color common Bash commands (cp, mv, ...)

Tags: bash, shell, sublimetext3

By default Sublime Text colors Bash keywords like `echo`, `for`, `time`, and some more. However, I like how gEdit also colors `cp`, `mv`, and some others that Sublime Text doesn't highlight. How can I make Sublime Text recognize `cp` and `mv` (and maybe others) as keyboards and highlight them, for Bash script files (.sh)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Command Palette ->  `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource` -> `ShellScript` -> `Shell-Unix-Generic.tmLanguage`

Scroll down to ~ line 1750 and add/edit  `support.function.builtin.shell`

```
<dict>
  <key>match</key>
    <string>(?&lt;![-/])\b(?:alias|bg|bind|break|builtin|caller|cd|command|....)\b</string>
  <key>name</key>
    <string>support.function.builtin.shell</string>
</dict>
```

Comment: I can't find PackageResourceViewer under Command Palette. Am I missing something?

Comment: [PackageResourceViewer](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer).  Install it via the `Command Palette` -> `Package Control : Install Package`.

Answer (score 8):

**1st:** Install the Package Control

Menu Tools -> the very bottom click on Install Package Control and wait a few seconds, it will tell you once successfully installed:

> Package Control was successfully installed

(Restart `sublime-text` for that menu item to disappear.)

**2nd:** View the Command Palette

Menu Tools -> at the very top click on Command Palette.

**3rd:** Search for Package Control: Install Package

Just type into the search box:

> Package Control: Install Package

And click on it.

**4th:** Install the PackageResourceViewer plugin

Just type into the search box:

> PackageResourceViewer

And click on it.

It will notify to about successful installation very shortly in the very bottom status bar.

**5th:** Open the resource viewer

View the Command Palette again.

Just type into the search box:

> PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource

And click on it.

**6th:** Open ShellScript resource

Just type into the search box:

> ShellScript

And click on it.

**7th:** Open Bash sublime-syntax configuration file

Just type into the search box:

> Bash.sublime-syntax

And click on it.

It will open a file.

**8th:** Search for `support.function.builtin.shell`

Search via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for this code:

> `support.function.builtin.shell`

**9th:** Edit the `match` line content to your liking

Out of the box this contains in the build 3126:

```
'(?<![-/])\b(?:alias|bg|bind|break|builtin|caller|cd|command|compgen|complete|dirs|disown|echo|enable|eval|exec|exit|false|fc|fg|getopts|hash|help|history|jobs|kill|let|logout|popd|printf|pushd|pwd|read|readonly|set|shift|shopt|source|suspend|test|times|trap|true|type|ulimit|umask|unalias|unset|wait)\b'
```

In later versions, I have tested build 3176, the file is **structured** heavily and **there is no longer a single line to edit**.

You will literally have to dig through the file and edit it to your liking.

**10th:** Save the file and continue working

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

You don't need to restart `sublime-text` in order for the new settings to apply.

Comment: The file `Shell-Unix-Generic.sublime-syntax` has only 8 lines and none of them matches `support.function.builtin.shell`

Comment: @NurShomik Thank you for bringing that up. I have just installed the latest build and can confirm that the Unix file does no longer serve our purpose. I have edited the answer, I hope it helps a little, but there is no longer a single line to edit.